# Mixed authentication modes: send both Kerberos token and username token over HTTPs with WCF

Tags: wcf, authentication, service, kerberos

Is it possible to send both username token and the kerberos token over HTTPs with WCF?

We are able to use custom binding with authentication mode set to 'UserNameOverTransport', which will include a username token in the SOAP header as per OASIS web services security standard.

Alternatively can set the authentication mode to 'KerberosOverTransport', which will include a Kerberos token in the SOAP header.

However the service we are trying to communicate has a requirement to authenticate use both kerberos token & username token. It doesn't seem to be possible with the existing authentication modes.

Comment: Is the service you are trying to communicate with a WCF service?  I thought a single endpoint could only have a single authentication mode.

Comment: No, we are interacting with webservices using JBoss ESB.

Answer (score 0):

The token (which is a Kerberos token) actually has the username embedded in it.  So if you need to communicate with a service that requires both then you'll want to use `KerberosOverTransport`.

You'll then want to pass the token to the [constructor of WindowsIdentity which asks for an IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx).

Once you have it constructed you can access the username via the [name property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name.aspx).  A piece of code that is almost what you need (sans the logging in bits) can be found here:

http://kseesharp.blogspot.com/2009/04/c-create-windowsidentity-from-userid.html